# Discrete and continuous actions in the same environment

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deterministic-policy, stochastic-policy

I am working on a RL environment that requires both discrete and continuous actions as input from the agent. I currently have a fine implementation of DDPG which I would like to use for the continuous part. But what about the discrete actions? Can DDPG output both a continuous and a discrete action? Or should I rather turn to a different algorithm?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about discretizing the continuous output?

For a binary decision:
$$
    Binary(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        0, & \text{for } x < 0.5\\
        1, & \text{for } x \geq 0.5\\
        \end{array}\right.
$$

For more than two choices you could pass an array of continuous output values into a softmax function and select the maximum as your discrete action.

Comment: The variable I would like to keep continuous is an angle. Unfortunately, I already have discretised it and it did not help, since the optimum is probably close to some non-trivial angle value.